# How to stop mediaplayer which continues to play after closing the activity

Tags: android, media-player

I have set up MediaPlayer to play list of music files from raw folder. This music player has pause and play buttons. the songs are listed using RecyclerView.

My challenge is whenever i exit activity the activity, music continues to play without stopping automatically.
Please help me i want the music player to stop on activity close.

This is **CustomMusicAdapter**

```js
public class CustomMusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Music> myArraylist;
    private ArrayList<Music> getUserModelListFiltered;
    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean flag=true;


    public CustomMusicAdapter(Context context, int custom_music_row, ArrayList<Music> myArraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.getUserModelListFiltered = myArraylist;
        this.myArraylist = myArraylist;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_music_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @SuppressLint("RecyclerView")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final Music music = myArraylist.get(position);
        holder.mTitle.setText(music.getName());
        holder.mDes.setText(music.getSinger());

        //Play Music Setup
        holder.mImageaplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (flag){
                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,music.getSong());
                    flag=false;
                }
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder.mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder. mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

        // stop player
        holder.mImageStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!flag){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    flag=true;
                }
                holder.mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myArraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null | charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = getUserModelListFiltered.size();
                    filterResults.values = getUserModelListFiltered;
                }else {
                    String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                    List<Music> resultData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Music music: getUserModelListFiltered){
                        if (music.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)){
                            resultData.add(music);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                    filterResults.values = resultData;
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

                myArraylist = (ArrayList<Music>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView_SongName, textView_artist;
        ImageView imageView_play, imageView_stop;
        private View convertview;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        public ViewHolder() {
            convertview = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
            textView_SongName = convertview.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            textView_artist = convertview.findViewById(R.id.txtSinger);
            imageView_play = convertview.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
            imageView_stop = convertview.findViewById(R.id.ivStop);

        }
    }
}
```

**This how i placed it in the code
Is it right?**

```js
// stop player
        holder.mImageStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!flag){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    flag=true;
                }
                public void onDestroy(){
                    if( CustomMusicAdapter !=null ){
                        CustomMusicAdapter.release()
                    }
                }
                holder.mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

            }
        });
```

**Tip1Activity.java**

```js
public class Tip1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Music> arrayList;
    private CustomMusicAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tip1);



        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Tip1Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(Tip1Activity.this, "songs!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

      

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(new Music("001 Veni, veni, Emmanuel", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.veni_emmanuel));
        arrayList.add(new Music("002 O come. O come Emmanuel", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.o_come_emmanuel));
        arrayList.add(new Music("003 Savior of the nations, come", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.savior_of_nations));
        arrayList.add(new Music("004 On Jordan's bank the Baptist's cry", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.on_jordans_bank));
        arrayList.add(new Music("005 Lo, he comes", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.lo_he_comes));
        arrayList.add(new Music("006 O Word that goest forth on high", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.o_word_that_goes_forth));
        arrayList.add(new Music("007 Wake, awake", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.wake_awake));
        arrayList.add(new Music("008 Rorate caeli", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.rorate_caeli));
        arrayList.add(new Music("009 Conditor alme siderum", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.conditor_alme_siderum));
        arrayList.add(new Music("010 Creator of the stars of night", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.creator_of_the_stars));



        adapter = new CustomMusicAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_music_row, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    }

   }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to close Catholic Mass Songs App?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Tip1Activity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });



        return  true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
                return true;

            //do more funtionality here

                


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

**Images of code error**

[image: Code error from Tip1Activity]
[image: code error from adapter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method in the adapter :

```
public class CustomMusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Music> myArraylist;
    private ArrayList<Music> getUserModelListFiltered;
    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean flag=true;


    public CustomMusicAdapter(Context context, int custom_music_row, ArrayList<Music> myArraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.getUserModelListFiltered = myArraylist;
        this.myArraylist = myArraylist;

    }

     public release(){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
     }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_music_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @SuppressLint("RecyclerView")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final Music music = myArraylist.get(position);
        holder.mTitle.setText(music.getName());
        holder.mDes.setText(music.getSinger());

        //Play Music Setup
        holder.mImageaplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (flag){
                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,music.getSong());
                    flag=false;
                }
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder.mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder. mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

        // stop player
        holder.mImageStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!flag){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    flag=true;
                }
                holder.mImageaplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myArraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null | charSequence.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = getUserModelListFiltered.size();
                    filterResults.values = getUserModelListFiltered;
                }else {
                    String searchChr = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                    List<Music> resultData = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Music music: getUserModelListFiltered){
                        if (music.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchChr)){
                            resultData.add(music);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.count = resultData.size();
                    filterResults.values = resultData;
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

                myArraylist = (ArrayList<Music>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView_SongName, textView_artist;
        ImageView imageView_play, imageView_stop;
        private View convertview;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        public ViewHolder() {
            convertview = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
            textView_SongName = convertview.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            textView_artist = convertview.findViewById(R.id.txtSinger);
            imageView_play = convertview.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
            imageView_stop = convertview.findViewById(R.id.ivStop);

        }
    }
}
```

override activity onDestroy() method

```
 public class Tip1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList<Music> arrayList;
        private CustomMusicAdapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tip1);
    
    
    
            Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Tip1Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(Tip1Activity.this, "songs!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    
          
    
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    
            recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);
    
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(new Music("001 Veni, veni, Emmanuel", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.veni_emmanuel));
            arrayList.add(new Music("002 O come. O come Emmanuel", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.o_come_emmanuel));
            arrayList.add(new Music("003 Savior of the nations, come", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.savior_of_nations));
            arrayList.add(new Music("004 On Jordan's bank the Baptist's cry", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.on_jordans_bank));
            arrayList.add(new Music("005 Lo, he comes", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.lo_he_comes));
            arrayList.add(new Music("006 O Word that goest forth on high", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.o_word_that_goes_forth));
            arrayList.add(new Music("007 Wake, awake", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.wake_awake));
            arrayList.add(new Music("008 Rorate caeli", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.rorate_caeli));
            arrayList.add(new Music("009 Conditor alme siderum", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.conditor_alme_siderum));
            arrayList.add(new Music("010 Creator of the stars of night", "SONGS OF WORSHIP", R.raw.creator_of_the_stars));
    
    
    
            adapter = new CustomMusicAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_music_row, arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    
        }
    
     
    
    onDestroy() {
      if( adapter !=null ){
        adapter.release()
      }
    }
    
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to close Catholic Mass Songs App?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Tip1Activity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_options, menu);
    
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);
    
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    
            searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    
    
    
            return  true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
    
                case R.id.item1:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
                    return true;
    
                //do more funtionality here
    
                    
    
    
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting errors can you help tell me make more emphases

Comment: How i placed it in the code that gave me error is pasted in the OP. Please i pasted what i did that gave me error above. thanks for helping me

Comment: Remove this from onclick. 
public void onDestroy(){
                    if( CustomMusicAdapter !=null ){
                        CustomMusicAdapter.release()
                    }
                }


From where you have called Adapter. onDestroy is an activity/fragment method.
you need to override in the activity or in the fragment.

Comment: Can you share your activity code from where you have called adater

Comment: Yes sir i have posted the activity above

Comment: I have updated my answer for your code. Please check

Comment: Thank sir, But i encountered code error. I posted the screenshot above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216558/discussion-between-kishan-maurya-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

Use interface with RecyclerView adapter, So that when you click on the play button you send id of raw file (eg : R.raw.o_word_that_goes_forth) in the interface and you can use comman media player in activity and now `onDistroy` method you can stop the media player.